# Looking to add a class trigger with popup to a button in my wordpress divi builder

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm not a coder and would love some assistance.

I'm adding the following trigger class to my wordpress site. I want a specific button to trigger this popup I've designed in Convertflow. Problem is, I'm not at all sure how to add this trigger class to my divi button module

Screenshot of button module:

[image]

The trigger class is `.cta-42808-trigger`

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is for *specific programming issues* so a question like this is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you cannot trigger a button using CSS: you need to use JS, i.e jQuery:

```
jQuery( ".cta-42808-trigger" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Triggered!" );
  //what you need to do goes here
});
```

Divi is problematic in general for coding stuff, maybe you need to find another approach to problem.